# Getting Array Index Out of Bounds Error

Tags: java, arrays

For some reason I am getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at Assignment25.main(Assignment25.java:80)

public static void main (String[] args){
long[] array = new long[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    int thefib = 39;
    array[i] = fib(thefib);
    thefib++;
}

int counter = 0;
int counter1 = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    gcd(array[counter], array[counter1]);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time = end - start;
    System.out.println("GCD time for " + (counter + 39) + " and " + (counter1 + 
        39) + " is " + time);
    counter++;
    counter1++;
}

counter = 0;
counter = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    gcd2(array[counter], array[counter1]);
    long end1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time1 = end1 - start1;
    System.out.println("GCD2 time for " + (counter + 39) + " and " + (counter1 + 
        39) + " is " + time1);
    counter++;
    counter1++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The reason is that you are using an index that's outside the array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you start your `counter1` from `1` and the `for` loops for `6` iterations, the `counter1` becomes 7 in the last iteration which gives the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Because the size of your `array` is 7 and you're trying to access the index `7` using `array[counter1]` when `counter1` becomes 7.

The maximum accessible index in array is always `array.length - 1`, in your case, `array[6]` is the last accessible index of your array.

Answer (score 1):

initial value of `counter1`is `1` and value of `counter1` will be `7` by `i=6`. But there isn't a index for array.

Answer (score 0):

Array is defined for size 7 and the iterations are carried only 6 times...so the exception

Answer (score 0):

When you are incrementing `counter` and `counter1`, you set `counter1` as `counter1` to be exactly `counter+1`. When `counter` is `array.length-1` your `counter1` is equal to `array.length` which is `7`.

As you intention is to compute gcd of two adjacent integer why not directly use `i` itself:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length -1 ; i++){ // <<---- array.length-1 = 6, i guess
    long start1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    gcd2(array[i], array[i+1]);
    // other code
```